# Polynomial fitting for Shading Correction

Tags: regression, optimization, computer-vision

I am reading the book [Optimization for Computer Vision](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4471-5283-5), and the first example of optimization is a regression for shading correction, in which the author proposes the following polynomial:

$p_s(c,x) = c_0 + c_1.u^2 + c_2.v^2 + c_3.u^2.v^2 + c_4.u^4 + c_5.v^4 + c_6.u^4.v^2 + c_7.u^2.v^4 + c_8.u^4.v^4 $

where $u = |x-x_c|$ and $v = |y-y_c|$ It is not clear how he end up in that polynomial (ideas?), or why he dropped the odd terms (he mentioned image symmetry). I generated a synthetic image which I would like to correct using the polynomial regression proposed in the book:

[image: shading]

I wrote an algorithm which loads this image, fills the matrix of location (polynomial) and solve the linear system:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def fuv(dim,loc):
    return abs(loc[0]-dim[0]),abs(loc[1]-dim[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    shade = cv2.imread('shade.png',0)
    dim,center = shade.shape, shade.shape/2
    pixels = dim[0]*dim[1]

    # Matrix A*x = b
    a = np.zeros(shape=(pixels,9))
    b = shade.reshape(pixels,1)
    b_norm = b/np.max(b)

    # Fill Matrix A (position information)
    for i in range(pixels):
        loc = [i/dim[1],i%dim[1]]
        [u,v] = fuv(center, loc)
        u2,v2 = u**2, v**2
        u4,v4 = u2*u2, v2*v2
        a[i] = [1, u2, v2, u2*v2, u4, v4, u4*v2, u2*v4, u4*v4]

    # Solve Linear System
    x,resid,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(a,b_norm)

    # What should I do now?
    for i in range(pixels):
        b[i] = np.dot(a[i], x)
    b = b.reshape(dim[0],dim[1])
    cv2.imwrite('/tmp/answer.png',b)
```

I believed my algorithm is correct to obtain the coefficients. At this point in the book, he mentions that you can use those coefficients to create a correction function $l_s$ which would remove the shade and this whole image should be white. But he does not tell you how to build this function using the coefficients. He shows already the results.

That's the moment I got stuck and I am not sure yet how to proceed. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Your first equation specifies, in the clearest possible terms, how to "build this function using the coefficients."

Comment: That was precisely what I did (b[i] = np.dot(a[i], x)), but results don't look anything like it a white image, that's why I figured there would be a trick somewhere